# PHP: install mysqlnd_ms fail : make: *** [php_mysqlnd_ms.lo] error 1

Tags: php, mysql, load-balancing, mysqlnd

I'm installing mysqlnd_ms package for php, but the make command reported an error:

```
make: *** [php_mysqlnd_ms.lo] Error 1

ERROR: `make' failed
```

**my PHP version:**

[root@uoo insFile]# php -v

PHP 5.6.12 (cli) (built: Aug 30 2015 00:04:44) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2015 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2015 Zend Technologies

**my OS:**

[root@uoo ~]# cat /etc/centos-release

CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)

**all php module that has  been installed:**

```
[root@uoo insFile]# php -m 
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
ereg
fileinfo
filter
gd
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mhash
mysql
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
pdo_sqlite
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
SPL
sqlite3
standard
sysvsem
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
```

**here is my installation process with pecl:**

> [root@uoo insFile]# pecl install mysqlnd_ms
>
> downloading mysqlnd_ms-1.5.2.tgz ...
>
> Starting to download mysqlnd_ms-1.5.2.tgz (385,916 bytes)
>
> ..............................................................................done:
>   385,916 bytes
>
> 36 source files, building
>
> running: phpize
>
> Configuring for:
>
> PHP Api Version:         20131106
>
> Zend Module Api No:      20131226
>
> Zend Extension Api No:   220131226
>
> building in /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootvgIJMs/mysqlnd_ms-1.5.2
>
> running: /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/configure
>
> checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
>
> checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
>
> checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
>
> checking for cc... cc
>
> checking whether the C compiler works... yes
>
> checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>
> checking for suffix of executables...
>
> checking whether we are cross compiling... no
>
> checking for suffix of object files... o
>
> checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
>
> checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
>
> checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
>
> checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
>
> checking for icc... no
>
> checking for suncc... no
>
> checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
>
> checking for system library directory... lib
>
> checking if compiler supports -R... no
>
> checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
>
> checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>
> checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>
> checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
>
> checking for PHP prefix... /usr/local/php
>
> checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/local/php/include/php
>   -I/usr/local/php/include/php/main -I/usr/local/php/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/php/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/php/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/php/include/php/ext/date/lib
>
> checking for PHP extension directory...
>   /usr/local/php/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-zts-20131226
>
> checking for PHP installed headers prefix...
>   /usr/local/php/include/php
>
> checking if debug is enabled... no
>
> checking if zts is enabled... no
>
> checking for re2c... no
>
> configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to
>   regenerate PHP parsers.
>
> checking for gawk... gawk
>
> checking whether to enable mysqlnd_ms support... yes, shared
>
> checking whether to enable table filter in mysqlnd_ms... no
>
> checking whether to query caching through mysqlnd_qc in mysqlnd_ms...
>   no
>
> checking for ld used by cc... /usr/bin/ld
>
> checking if the linker (/usr/bin/ld) is GNU ld... yes
>
> checking for /usr/bin/ld option to reload object files... -r
>
> checking for BSD-compatible nm... /usr/bin/nm -B
>
> checking whether ln -s works... yes
>
> checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
>
> checking for ANSI C header files... yes
>
> checking for sys/types.h... yes
>
> checking for sys/stat.h... yes
>
> checking for stdlib.h... yes
>
> checking for string.h... yes
>
> checking for memory.h... yes
>
> checking for strings.h... yes
>
> checking for inttypes.h... yes
>
> checking for stdint.h... yes
>
> checking for unistd.h... yes
>
> checking dlfcn.h usability... yes
>
> checking dlfcn.h presence... yes
>
> checking for dlfcn.h... yes
>
> checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
>
> checking command to parse /usr/bin/nm -B output from cc object... ok
>
> checking for objdir... .libs
>
> checking for ar... ar
>
> checking for ranlib... ranlib
>
> checking for strip... strip
>
> checking if cc supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
>
> checking for cc option to produce PIC... -fPIC
>
> checking if cc PIC flag -fPIC works... yes
>
> checking if cc static flag -static works... no
>
> checking if cc supports -c -o file.o... yes
>
> checking whether the cc linker (/usr/bin/ld -m elf_x86_64) supports
>   shared  libraries... yes
>
> checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
>
> checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
>
> checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
>
> checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
>
> checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
>
> checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
>
> checking whether to build static libraries... no
>
> creating libtool
>
> appending configuration tag "CXX" to libtool
>
> configure: creating ./config.status
>
> config.status: creating config.h
>
> running: make
>
> /bin/sh /tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootr7CW9Q/mysqlnd_ms-1.5.2/libtool
>   --mode=compile cc
>
> -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms -DPHP_ATOM_INC
>
> -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootr7CW9Q/mysqlnd_ms-1.5.2/include
>
> -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootr7CW9Q/mysqlnd_ms-1.5.2/main
>
> -I/tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms -I/usr/local/php/include/php
>
> -I/usr/local/php/include/php/main -I/usr/local/php/include/php/TSRM
>
> -I/usr/local/php/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/php/include/php/ext
>
> -I/usr/local/php/include/php/ext/date/lib  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2
>
> -c /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c -o php_mysqlnd_ms.lo
>
> mkdir .libs
>
> cc -I. -I/tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms -DPHP_ATOM_INC
>   -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootr7CW9Q/mysqlnd_ms-1.5.2/include     -I/tmp/pear/temp/pear-build-rootr7CW9Q/mysqlnd_ms-1.5.2/main     -I/tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms -I/usr/local/php/include/php     -I/usr/local/php/include/php/main -I/usr/local/php/include/php/TSRM     -I/usr/local/php/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/php/include/php/ext     -I/usr/local/php/include/php/ext/date/lib -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2     -c /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php_mysqlnd_ms.o   /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:
>   In function ‘zif_mysqlnd_ms_get_last_used_connection’:
>
> /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:293:2: warning: passing
>   argument 2 of ‘zval_to_mysqlnd’ makes integer from pointer without a
>   cast [enabled by default]
>
> if (!(proxy_conn = zval_to_mysqlnd(handle TSRMLS_CC))) {
>   ^    In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/mysqlnd_ms.h:40:0,
>
> from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:34:
>                   /usr/local/php/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h:37:18:
>   note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void ***’
>
> PHPAPI MYSQLND * zval_to_mysqlnd(zval * zv, const unsigned int
>   client_api_capabilities, unsigned int * save_client_api_capabilities
>   TSRMLS_DC);
>
> ^
>   /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:293:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘zval_to_mysqlnd’
>
> if (!(proxy_conn = zval_to_mysqlnd(handle TSRMLS_CC))) {
>   ^    In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/mysqlnd_ms.h:40:0,
>
> from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:34:
>                   /usr/local/php/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h:37:18:
>   note: declared here
>
> PHPAPI MYSQLND * zval_to_mysqlnd(zval * zv, const unsigned int
>   client_api_capabilities, unsigned int * save_client_api_capabilities
>   TSRMLS_DC);
>
> ^
>   /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c: In function ‘zif_mysqlnd_ms_get_last_gtid’:
>
> /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:333:2: warning: passing
>   argument 2 of ‘zval_to_mysqlnd’ makes integer from pointer without a
>   cast [enabled by default]
>   if (!(proxy_conn = zval_to_mysqlnd(handle TSRMLS_CC))) {
>   ^    In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/mysqlnd_ms.h:40:0,
>
> from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:34:
>                   /usr/local/php/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h:37:18:
>   note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void ***’
>   PHPAPI MYSQLND * zval_to_mysqlnd(zval * zv, const unsigned int
>   client_api_capabilities, unsigned int * save_client_api_capabilities
>   TSRMLS_DC);
>
> ^
>   /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:333:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘zval_to_mysqlnd’
>
> if (!(proxy_conn = zval_to_mysqlnd(handle TSRMLS_CC))) {
>    ^    In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/mysqlnd_ms.h:40:0,
>
> from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:34:
>
> /usr/local/php/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h:37:18:
>   note: declared here
>
> PHPAPI MYSQLND * zval_to_mysqlnd(zval * zv, const unsigned int
>   client_api_capabilities, unsigned int * save_client_api_capabilities
>   TSRMLS_DC);
>
> ^
>   /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:373:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘ms_ori  mysqlnd_conn_methods->store_result’
>   makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled▽by default]
>    if (!(res = MS_CALL_ORIGINAL_CONN_DATA_METHOD(store_result)(conn TSRMLS_CC))) {
>   ^
>   /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:373:3: note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void ***’
>
> /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:373:3: error: too few
>   arguments to function ‘ms_orig_mysqlnd_conn_methods->store_result’
>
> /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c: In function
>   ‘zif_mysqlnd_ms_set_qos’:
>
> /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:506:2: warning: passing
>   argument 2 of ‘zval_to_mysqlnd’ makes integer from pointer without a
>   cast [enabled by default]
>   if (!(proxy_conn = zval_to_mysqlnd(handle TSRMLS_CC))) {
>
> ^
>
> In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/mysqlnd_ms.h:40:0,
>
> from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:34:
>                   /usr/local/php/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h:37:18:
>   note: expected ‘unsigned int’ but argument is of type ‘void ***’
>
> PHPAPI MYSQLND * zval_to_mysqlnd(zval * zv, const unsigned int
>   client_api_capabilities, unsigned int * save_client_api_capabilities
>   TSRMLS_DC);
>
> ^
>
> /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:506:2: error: too few arguments to function ‘zval_to_mysqlnd’
>
> if (!(proxy_conn = zval_to_mysqlnd(handle TSRMLS_CC))) {
>
> ^
>
> In file included from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/mysqlnd_ms.h:40:0,
>
> from /tmp/pear/temp/mysqlnd_ms/php_mysqlnd_ms.c:34:
>                   /usr/local/php/include/php/ext/mysqlnd/mysqlnd_reverse_api.h:37:18:
>   note: declared here
>
> PHPAPI MYSQLND * zval_to_mysqlnd(zval * zv, const unsigned int
>   client_api_capabilities, unsigned int * save_client_api_capabilities
>   TSRMLS_DC);
>
> ^
>
> make: *** [php_mysqlnd_ms.lo] Error 1
>
> ERROR: `make' failed

Comment: Is there a reason you don't install it via the systems package manager?

Comment: @Gerald Schneider, you mean the pecl?  I have tried to install by pecl ,but still   report the same error.

Comment: No, I mean apt, yum, or whatever package system your distribution uses.

Comment: @Gerald Schneider, my os is centos 7 ,but I think i can't  install mysqlnd_ms by yum . mysqlnd_ms  is a pecl  package. [install mysqlnd_ms](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.setup.php)

Comment: There is a package for Centos 7 with PHP 5.6 available here: http://pkgs.org/centos-7/remi-x86_64/php56-php-pecl-mysqlnd-ms-1.6.0-4.svn333506.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html Haven't used it though, so I can't say how reliable it is.

Comment: I'm glad to try it . Thank you ,@Gerald Schneider

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the exact same error with almost the same configuration

Comment: @BeBest, Sorry, I did not succeed.

Comment: finally I've compiled their last svn trunk. svn checkout http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/mysqlnd_ms/trunk

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
svn checkout http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/mysqlnd_ms/trunk/ && cd trunk && phpize && ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config && make
```

then run `make install`

then restart your apache.

I only tried this on php5.6. I'm not sure if this works on other version.

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking hours and hours on the google finally the Clark's solution worked on cpanel just a bit of tweak

For cpanel I changed the command to:

```
svn checkout http://svn.php.net/repository/pecl/mysqlnd_ms/trunk/ && cd trunk && /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/phpize && ./configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php-config && make; make install
```

You also need to create and add the extension name in
`/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/`:

```
cd /opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/
cat >> mysqlnd_ms.ini << EOF
extension=mysqlnd_ms.so
EOF
```

You can see result with `php -m`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. You can [search for similar questions](//stackoverflow.com/search), or refer to the related and linked questions on the right-hand side of the page to find an answer. If you have a related but different question, [ask a new question](//stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), and include a link to this one to help provide context. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully install it via RPM package install.  The links below may help you, depending on OS and PHP version you currently have. I mention this detail since this was originally posted a few years ago.

[www.rpmfind.net](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=php-pecl-svn&submit=Search%20...)

[centos.pkgs.org](https://centos.pkgs.org/)

I simply followed the instructions from CentOS packages and the php pecl-svn extension installed with no issues on the Redhat 6.9 PHP 5.6 server.  Hopefully the same works for you.